# Does CakePhp recursively pull back data?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, database-relations, cakephp-model

So i have the following database situation:

Event has a link to many TroupeInfo,
TroupeInfo has a sing link to TrouperCategory

As a test I created a controller for TroupeInfo, and it pulls back the correct trouperCategory entry, however if I run the controller for Event, it pulls back just the TroupeInfo dataset, but it does not run the TroupeInfo connection to TrouperCateogory, so my question is does cakephp not recursively pull back data, I am looking to get results like.

Event
   TroupeInfo
      Trouepr Category

Comment: I respectfully ask to know why this question was suddenly down voted nearly 4 months later, and within seconds of another one of my questions being down-voted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687238/c-windows-7-get-symbolic-names-of-installed-drivers).  If this is a bad question, I would like to know, so that I can either fix it or delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to read about and use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).