# C++ Windows 7 Get Symbolic Names of Installed drivers

Tags: c++, windows-7, driver, plug-and-play

I have an application, that needs to talk to a piece of custom hardware. I know roughly the format that the driver will register a symbolic name, however based on some physical switches on the card, the card will have a somewhat dynamic name.  My question is is there way to find the registered symbolic name, or find the driver and create the symbolic name.

My application use the symbolic name for operations like CreateFile(), WriteFile(), etc.

**Update**

The driver is PNP, so it really only makes the one subkey under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\V70QT\`, and I will have potentially more than 1 card. I thought for a second there, that I could use this registry key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\V70QT\Enum]
"Count"=dword:00000001
"NextInstance"=dword:00000001
"0"="PCI\\VEN_10B5&DEV_2021&SUBSYS_202110B5&REV_03\\4&33c89357&0&08F0"
```

Because the symbolic key name gets built in a format similar to V70QTX_Y, where X is the card ID (switches on hardware), and Y is the channel (irrelevant here). I thought I could build the name up using the "NextInstance" value however that will not work, as the card could have a switch ID of like 4, and be the first instance.

Comment: I respectfully ask to know why this question was suddenly down voted over a month later, and within seconds of another one of my questions being down-voted (shttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277684/does-cakephp-recursively-pull-back-data). If this is a bad question, I would like to know, so that I can either fix it or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your driver shows up under `[HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services]`, it would simply be a matter of enumerating the subkeys there.

Comment: So, not driver names but device names?

Comment: I guess I am not sure, this is where I have a hole in my knowledge. I know when you install the driver for the card (in device manager), it is going to registr a symbolic names, based on it's card id. And I can uses the card right away, no reboot required. So device names... probably...